# Adding Account Team for Account with different user

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am currently working on a requirement where users should be able to add account teams for accounts they do not own. I have been trying to do this through apex. When I click on a button I am changing the sharing settings for the record and am trying to show the standard account team page. This is working to some extent that I am able to add the team members but I am not able to select the level of access for them. I have attached the screen shot.
[image]

I have also added the code where I am redirecting to the standard page and the Apex used.

```
function pageRed(){
var url  = '/opp/salesteaminsert.jsp?retURL=%2F'+'{!acct.id}'+'&id='+'{!acct.id}';
subTabTitle = 'Account Teams';
alert(sforce.console.isInConsole());
if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
    sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(result) {
        sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, url, true, subTabTitle, null);
    });
}else{
    window.top.location.href = url;
}}
```

The above is the Javascript i have used in VFPage.

```
public PageReference manualShare(){

    AccountShare jobShr = new AccountShare();
    jobShr.AccountId = acct.id;
    jobShr.UserOrGroupId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    jobShr.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
    jobShr.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
    jobShr.CaseAccessLevel = 'Edit';
    jobShr.RowCause = 'Manual';
    Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(jobShr,false);

    if(sr.isSuccess()){
        System.debug('It is a smashing success');
        return null;
    }
    else {
        Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];
        if(err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION  &&  err.getMessage().contains('AccessLevel')){
            System.debug('It is a smashing Failure'+err.getStatusCode());
            return null;
        }
        else{
            System.debug(' 2 It is a smashing Failure'+err.getStatusCode());            
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is the apex method I have used to give access.

Please let me what I am doing wrong here. How do I add the Account/Case/Opportunity Access.

Thanks

Comment: what is the OWD on the account?

Comment: the OWD on the account is Private... But I am granting the Edit access to the user through the Apex. @Rao

Comment: I assume you are recreating the account team add screen, why do you want to grant edit access through apex? Can you not use public groups and add the same set of users and allow them to edit the accounts that way they can edit the account team. If your argument is that you do not want users to edit account, you cannot implement this logic since users need to have edit on accounts to add members to an account. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=accountteam_add.htm&language=en